chartjs create a custom mode
From chartjs documentation it's possibile to create a custom mode, defaults are: 'active',"show","resize","hide". It's not clear how to create a custom one and what attributes can be animationed.
Thanks
I've tried with adding a custom transitions but how create that? documentation seems to be lack of some useful sample

From the docs, a custom transition, say myTransition is to be used as the argument to update, i.e, chart.update('myTransition'); that update will take its parameters from the chart's options.transitions.myTransition; here's a basic example. It would be more fitting for a stackoverflow question to say what exactly are you trying to achieve, and include what you have tried and your minimal reproducible example.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
